# Redirect to another html page if the login is success with react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React, 
I would like to know if it is possible with React js. 
for example I have a login modal, and I tried to write a basic script and take de value of inputs with this code `document.getElementById("email");` but not working. please help me, that I can use? or 
how do it ? please, oh and sorry for my english :D

Comment: Seems like you're asking two separate questions here? I would encourage you to go through the React Documentation, where [your problem is explained in depth](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html).

Comment: sorry for that, and  thanks so much for the link :D

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible.

1. You do not need to use document.getElementById("email"); Check how
   work with inputs https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html
2. I suggest to add React Router https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial it helps you to redirect user when it's necessary in correct and elegant way.

Example:

```
export default class Login extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      login: '',
      password: '',
    };
    this.onChangeInput = this.onChangeInput.bind(this);
    this.onLogin = this.onLogin.bind(this);
    this.onHandleLogin = this.onHandleLogin.bind(this);
  }

  onHandleLogin() {
    /* using react router you can do this */
    browserHistory.push('/todo');
  }
  onShowLoginError() {
    this.setState({
      showError: true,
    });
  }

  onChangeInput({ target: { value, name } }) {
    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
    });
  }

  onLogin(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    /* check here credentials */
    /* I do request to server */
    const init = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(this.state),
    };
    /* if login is correct call this.onHandleLogin() */
    sendRequest('login', init, () => {})
      .then(() => this.onHandleLogin())
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Login page...</h1>
        <form>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="login">User name:</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="login"
              value={this.state.login}
              onChange={this.onChangeInput}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="password"
              value={this.state.password}
              onChange={this.onChangeInput}
            />
          </div>
          <button onClick={this.onLogin}>Log in</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The full example see here https://github.com/Aksana-Tsishchanka/react-routing/blob/master/src/components/Login.jsx

Answer (score 2):

I'm very new also but wanted to help.
Along my project in react i found a good solution for that with https://firebase.google.com/ authentication that let me also offer facebook, google and more login methods and recommend you to try it, also has a very good documentation.

I think you should implement something like:

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (this.state.userLoggedin) {  // you should save in state your logged user
       // actions if user is logged in  
    } else {
       // actions if not user logged in
      }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for you answer, in fact I use firebase authentication but I know how redirect to other page with is success, for example in the home page is the login, and if is success Redirect you to AppWeb (other file or class).

Comment: Are you using react-router? I'm testing it and is exactly to manage routes inside your app, Check https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router